# Way to run Kusto query on command line against JSON

Tags: kql

Is there a Linux command line tool, like `jq`, but that runs Kusto queries?
So I could do something like this:

```
$ cat somedata.json | kql 'where user="ml" | count'
42
```

I do mean run it on my own server, not using an Azure service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a command-line tool, but it runs against a Kusto cluster see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-cli

You can run it against the "help" cluster (https://help.kusto.windows.net) which is a public cluster